# Getting all the codec in a pack

Tags: 11.04, codecs

I installed Ubuntu 11.04, now when ever i try to play mp3 or any such files it searchs for codecs.
Is there any pack which bundles all the required codec for famous formats [mp3, mpg, wmv, flv, ...] ?

Comment: Yes, look it up on the Ubuntu Software Center, just type mp3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this from Unity you can use the software center as in the following:

1. Press <kbd>Super</kbd> (the Windows key).
2. Type `software center` and press Ubuntu Software Center.
3. In the search dialog of Ubuntu Software Center type `ubuntu-restricted-extras`
4. This should show you the package containing the codecs. Mark it and press install.

Comment: it installted properly but still it search for mp3 plugin

Comment: @Sourav When does it search for mp3 plugin?

Comment: when ever i try top open an MP3 file with the default player.

Comment: @Sourav Do you mean Banshee? What happens if you try another player?

Answer (score 1):

You can install "ugly" GStreamer plugin from Software Center or issue the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly
```

Comment: Package 'gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly' has no installation candidate

Answer (score 1):

Just click [this link](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/ubuntu-restricted-extras). It will automatically install codecs.